# How to drop multiple columns in R using select?I just don't know where to put the “-”

Tags: r

Create the dataframe taxis_smaller that excludes the columns VendorID, rate, and store_and_fwd_flag.

```
taxis_smaller <- taxis %>% select(taxis,-c("VendorID","rate","store_and_fwd_flag"))
 select(taxis,-c("VendorID","rate","store_and_fwd_flag"))
```

Comment: If you are piping in to `select`, don't repeat the data.frame name. Just use `taxis_smaller <- taxis %>% select(-c("VendorID","rate","store_and_fwd_flag"))`

Answer (score 1):

An alternate approach to `-` placement when piping `select` is:

```
taxis_smaller <- taxis %>% 
    select(-VendorID, -rate, -store_and_fwd_flag)
```

Comment: Are you saying you can't put a minus before a vector of names? `select(iris, -c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width"))` seems to work just fine for me at least. I don't think you need to repeat the `-` a bunch of times.

Comment: That definitely works! I think the repeated `-` looks a bit cleaner than  `-c(...)` when dealing with a few columns.